# Proving that $f(x,y) = (x^3 y)/(x^3-y^6)$ for $y \neq x^2$ and $0$ for $y = x^2$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

how do I prove that the function above is discontinuous at (0,0)?

My first idea is to take an arbitrary pair $(a,b)\in R^2$ with $b = x^2$.

Solving $f(a,b)$ would be dividing by zero and since this is not defined the function can't be continuous in any point $(a,b)$ with $b =a^2$. 
But since the definition says that $f$ is zero for any pair like $(a,b)$ I guess this Proof doesn't work.

I think another good way would be the ε-δ method. 
I also heard about a method where you first fix the x-value and plug in different y's and then vice versa.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You won't prove it simply because the function doesn't even exist at $(0,0)$.  Edit: Please ignore, I didn't read the question close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Approach $(0,0)$ along the curve $x^3=y^6+y^7$.

Comment: Could you (or someone else) illustrate this a bit ? Shall I just plug in the values and then take the limit ?

Comment: You already have a path for which the limit is $0$.  The simplest is the curve $y=x^2$, along which the function is identically $0$. But probably most paths you try will give limit $0$. Now let's use the path I suggested. The top is $x^3y$ which is $(y^6+y^7)y$. The bottom is $x^3-y^6$ which is $y^7$. So we are looking for the limit of $\frac{y^7+y^8}{y^7}$. By cancellation this is the limit of $1+y$, which is $1$. Different from the $0$ which we get along another path, so the overall limit does not exist.

Comment: By the way, if I replace the path $x^3=y^6+y^7$ by the path $x^3=y^6+3y^7$ the limit along the new path will be $\frac{1}{3}$.